Solving simultaneous nonlinear equations, but code is failed
eqns = {r*x*Exp[1 - x] - (a*x^2*y)/(1 + x) == 
    0, (e1*a*x*y)/(1 + x) - \[Alpha]*y - (b*y*z)/(1 + y) == 
    0, (e2*b*y*z)/(1 + y) - \[Beta]*z == 0};
nonNegativityConstraints = {r >= 0, a >= 0, e1 >= 0, \[Alpha] >= 0, 
   b >= 0, e2 >= 0, \[Beta] >= 0, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0};
eq = Join[eqns, nonNegativityConstraints]
Solve[eq, {x, y, z}, Reals]

Code is not running. It shows "Solve:: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve."
Help me please. I want to find solution as defined here.

Btw, Mathematica is not sympy nor sagemath. No need to declare symbol before using it as symbol.   So no need to write x=Symbol["x"] in order to use x as symbol.
Mathematica is a real symbolic system, and hence these things are not needed.
As for your main question, if you add the other symbols, then Solve can now solve it.
eqns = {r*x*Exp[1 - x] - (a*x^2*y)/(1 + x) == 
    0, (e1*a*x*y)/(1 + x) - alpha*y - (b*y*z)/(1 + y) == 
    0, (e2*b*y*z)/(1 + y) - beta*z == 0};
nonNegativityConstraints = {r >= 0, a >= 0, e1 >= 0, alpha >= 0, 
   b >= 0, e2 >= 0, beta >= 0, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0};
eq = Join[eqns, nonNegativityConstraints]
Solve[eq, {x, y, z, r, a, e2, e1, alpha, beta, b}, Reals]


ps. The title of your post says differential equation. But I see no differential equation anywhere?

Still showing errors: Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.    for ... eqns = {rxExp[1 - x] - (ax^2y)/(1 + x) ==
0, (e1axy)/(1 + x) - [Alpha]y - (byz)/(1 + y) ==
0, (e2by*z)/(1 + y) - [Beta]*z == 0};
nonNegativityConstraints = {r >= 0, a >= 0, e1 >= 0, [Alpha] >= 0,
b >= 0, e2 >= 0, [Beta] >= 0, x >= 0, y >= 0, z >= 0};
eq = Join[eqns, nonNegativityConstraints]
Solve[eq, {x, y, z}, Reals]

@SKSARIFHASSAN  Still showing errors:  but you are not using the code I posted, that is why.

I want only $x, y, z$. I am not able to get the result that is coming out of the code you provided.

@SKSARIFHASSAN I am using V 14.1 and as you can see, Mathematica gives the solution for $x,y,z$ there, along with all the others. But you need to pass all other variables to get all solution. Now you can simply filter out $x,y,z$ only out from the final solution.  You see the solution says $x=0,y=0,z=0$
